# Comparing the dimension of an algebraic variety and its tangent space

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-varieties, tangent-spaces

If $X\subseteq\mathbb{A}^N$ is a variety of dimension $n$, I would like to prove that $$\dim T_xX\geq\dim X=n$$ for any point $x\in X$.

My first attempt was to use the Krull's Principal Ideal Theorem, because if $\dim X=n$, then we need at least $N-n$ generators for $I(X)$, say $F_1,...,F_m$. Then, their differentials at $x$ define $T_xX$, since $T_xX=V(d_xF_1,...,d_xF_m)$, and by applying the above theorem to its coordinate ring, we conclude that $\dim T_xX\geq N-m$ and I can't continue, because $m\geq N-n$.

I came up with this question because the class notes I was reading define a point to be non-singular when $\dim X=N-\textrm{rank }J(x)$, where $J(x)$ denotes the Jacobian matrix at $x$, and claim that a point is singular if, and only if, $\textrm{rank }J(x)<N-n$ (why couldn't it be strictly greater instead?), from where we conclude that $\dim T_xX>\dim X$ (since $T_xX$ is the null space of $J(x)$ and we use the Rank-Nullity Theorem).

Comment: Good question and good attempt - you're on the right track, but you need a slight adjustment. Instead of considering the full coordinate ring of $X$, one should consider the local ring of $X$ at $x$: when $X$ is irreducible, this is a local ring of dimension $\dim X$, and for any noetherian local ring $A$ of dimension $d$, $\dim A \leq \dim_{A/m} m/m^2$ as explained in the linked duplicate.

Comment: Try proving that for any noetherian local ring $(R, \mathfrak{m})$, we have that $\dim R \leq \dim_k \mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2$. Hint: Use the nakayama lemma.

Comment: Thank you both for answering me and sorry for the duplicate question. I was not used to using the local ring at a point to compute the dimension of the variety, but I understood the solution provided on the link.